# How to enable clang static analyzer flags from clang-tidy for alpha (experimental) checkers?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang-tidy, clang-static-analyzer, scan-build

I'm trying to run the clang analyzer through its clang-tidy interface, but I need to pass the clang analyzer an additional flag. Specifically, I want to run an alpha checker for nondeterminism with

```
clang-tidy -allow-enabling-analyzer-alpha-checkers -checks=clang-analyzer-alpha.nondeterminism.*
```

but it gives me the error:

`error: checker cannot be enabled with analyzer option 'aggressive-binary-operation-simplification' == false [clang-diagnostic-error]`

since it depends on having the flag `aggressive-binary-operation-simplification=true` (false by default) set for the clang analyzer.

If I'm limited to using clang-tidy, is this possible?

I've taken a look at the options available, and none seem to fit the bill. (e.g. using `--extra-arg(-before)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag `--extra-arg=aggressive-binary-operation-simplification` wasn't actually necessary in the end. I believe the error was in my build process.

Boris' answer is close, but it's missing the alpha checker call and it isn't necessary to use the `--extra-arg` flags specifying.

For reference, the final fixed call is:

> clang-tidy <source_file> -allow-enabling-analyzer-alpha-checkers -checks=clang-analyzer-alpha.nondeterminism.* -- -ffile-prefix-map=</my/include/path/>**=** -I</my/include/path/ same for the -ffile-prefix-map>

Answer (score 1):

clang-tidy --extra-arg=-Xclang --extra-arg=-analyzer-config --extra-arg=-Xclang --extra-arg=aggressive-binary-operation-simplification=true -p ***the_build_dir_contain_the_file_compile_commands.json*** *your_source_file_pathname*